# Using non-AWS S3 storage with Django?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

I have an S3 storage which is not hosted by AWS. I tried my AWS account as a file-storage, which worked fine, however, when I switch the credentials to the non-AWS provider I get:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

in the django logs, and

> ClientError at /admin/api/metabolomicsmzxml/add/
> An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

displayed in the browser.

I use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) with the following configuration:q
:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWSS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ca-central-1'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_VERIFY = True
AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = 'example.com:443'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Is it possible to use `django-storages` and `boto3` with a non-AWS provider? Are there other packages that I should try?

---

I tried

```
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'example.com:443'
```

and

```
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'example.com'
```

then I get

> ValueError: Invalid endpoint: ...

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked.

I had to change the format of the S3 endpoint to:

```
'https://example.com'
```

And it works! I can now use a non-AWS S3 storage with django.

Comment: Just curious, are you using Digital Ocean Spaces?

Comment: No, its a educational provider.